# NSMutableArray search

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar and I am performing a search on an array and displaying result. The search works perfect for the first letter but the application crashes when I add a letter in search or even when I press backspace. Here is the code I am using:

```
for (NSString *sTemp in arrCatSearch)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:strSearch options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [searchArray addObject:[catalog.catalogItems objectAtIndex:i]];
        i++;
    }
```

The application crashes in the NSRange line.

Comment: Can you provide the crash error?

Comment: before for loop add this stmt [searchArray removeAllObjects];,,it will work

Comment: one more thing may be you miss i=0 before for loop

Comment: In which method you have above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `NSRange` like :

```
NSRange result = [searchString rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
```

in search bar's delegate methods

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you a better result.

```
if ([sTemp rangeOfString: strSearch options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
{
    if (![searchArray containsObject: [catalog.catalogItems objectAtIndex: i]])
    {
        [searchArray addObject: [catalog.catalogItems objectAtIndex: i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching an array for results should be done with the NSPredicate class:

```
        NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",searchBar.text];

    //filter array based on the predicate
   searchArray = [arrCatSearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```